# TextField description RichFaces

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces

i'm working with richfaces , i need to show "X" message when the field is clicked like the photo. This is my code in xhtml :

```
    <!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

    <rich:panel>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="Name:" />
            <h:inputText label="Name" id="name" required="true"
                value="#{loginAction.username}">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
            </h:inputText>
            <rich:message for="name" style="color:red;">
                <f:facet name="errorMarker">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/img/error.gif" />
                </f:facet>
            </rich:message>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <a4j:commandButton value="Validate" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

i want something like this , before submited , only when the field is clicked :

[image: FieldText Descriptor]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use richfaces' [`<rich:tooltip/>`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tooltip&skin=blueSky) to display a customizable and skinnable tooltip next to your text box. From the the demo example:

```
<h:inputText label="Name" id="name" required="true" value="#{loginAction.username}">
            <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
               <rich:tooltip followMouse="false" showEvent="onclick" showDelay="1500" styleClass="tooltip-custom-body" layout="block">
            <span style="white-space: nowrap"> This tool-tip content is also <strong>pre-rendered</strong> to the
                page.<br /> </span>
     </rich:tooltip>
 </h:inputText>
```